# Scala - how to force a specific order of Traits

Tags: scala, traits

While the order of traits metter during their mixing then how I can force their order in a specific way.
For example I have this:

```
val t = new Wink with Dash with Right with Left
```

and I want to put conditions, like `if Right NOT Left` and let say `Dash COMES FIRST THEN Right OR Left`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish such restrictions on ways of mixing traits is following:

```
trait Dash[T <: Dash[T]]
trait Right extends Dash[Right]
trait Left extends Dash[Left]

val t = new Wink with Dash[Right]
```

This way, `[T <: Dash[T]]` forces us to provide either Right or Left trait right away. (Right **or** Left in your requirements)

On the other hand Due to extension `extends Dash[Right]`, Right or Left trait can not be mixed in without use of Dash. (Dash **comes first** in your requirements)

It also sounds as if you are checking some condition in order to decide between Right or Left. This could be done like this:

```
val t = if (p) new Wink with Dash[Right] else new Wink with Dash[Left]
```

Comment: your answer is guiding me to think in a solution but still I cannot extend it, generalize: does it mean that is hard to reach a state where I can say `new Wink with Dash with Right with Straight with Colon` (many stackable traits which order matter) also where aren't allowed to be mixed two traits which functions are alternative (like Left, Straight and Right)

Comment: also, `Right`  or `Left` logically in my implementation doesn't extend nothing from `Dash`, I wouldn't like to mix it in every other trait just because of this reason.  :(

Comment: I am sorry, but I think there is no way in writing `new Wink with Dash with Right with Straight with Colon` and let the compiler do the rest in terms of constrains. Putting restrictions by extending traits is the weapon of choice I would pick here. One has to think of a certain hierarchy though. But maybe someone else might come up with a better idea on handling this.